# SelectOneMenu doesn't have any value to choose from

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsf, tomcat7

when I try to display employee.jsp page I am not able to select employee. 
It looks like SelectOneMenu doesn't work. Am I missing something in that tag (line 20)?

I checked and the database has table employee with some employee data.
I have connection to database. I use mysql database. You can see connection to this database in persistance.xml file.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; 
charset=US-ASCII" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Employee Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
    <h2><center>Welcome to Employee Home Page</center></h2>
    <br><br>
    <h:form>
    <h2>
        Select an Employee Number from the drop down:
    </h2>
    <br><br>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="selEmpNo"
        valueChangeListener="#{employee.employeeReport}"
        onchange="submit()">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{employee.empNoList}" id="emp"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
    <br><br>
    <h2>
    <h:outputText value="Employee Name: "></h:outputText>
    <h:outputText value="#{employee.empName}"/>
    <br><br>
    <h:outputText value="Employee Number: "/>
    <h:outputText value="#{employee.empNo}"/>
    <br><br>
    <h:outputText value="Name of the IBU: "/>
    <h:outputText value="#{employee.ibu}"/>
    <br><br>
    <h:outputText value="Designation: "/>
    <h:outputText value="#{employee.designation}"/> </h2>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;
charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <f:view>
            <h2>
                <center>
                <h:outputLabel> Welcome!!!</h:outputLabel>
                </center>
                <h:outputLink value="employee.jsp">Employee Details</h:outputLink>
            </h2>
        </f:view>
    </body>
</html>
</html>
```

```
package employee;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

public class EmployeeBean {

    private String empName;
    private String ibu;
    private String designation;
    private int empNo;
    //This is used to dynamically populate the drop down with employee numbers
    List<SelectItem> empNoList;
    List<EmployeeEntity>empList;

    public EmployeeBean(){
        this.empNoList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        /*Populating Employee Number in the drop down - Dynamic */
        empList = new EmployeeService().getEmployeeList();
        Iterator<EmployeeEntity>iterator = empList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            EmployeeEntity employee = iterator.next();
            SelectItem item = new SelectItem(employee.getEmpNo());
            empNoList.add(item);
        }
        System.out.println(empNoList);
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getIbu() {
        return ibu;
    }

    public void setIbu(String ibu) {
        this.ibu = ibu;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getEmpNoList() {
        return empNoList;
    }

    public void setEmpNoList(List<SelectItem> empNoList) {
        this.empNoList = empNoList;
    }

    public List<EmployeeEntity> getEmpList() {
        return empList;
    }

    public void setEmpList(List<EmployeeEntity> empList) {
        this.empList = empList;

    }
    /*Eventlistener - for fetching an employee record based on the selection of employee
        number from the drop down*/
    public void employeeReport(ValueChangeEvent event){
        int empNo = Integer.parseInt((String)event.getNewValue());
        EmployeeEntity employee = new EmployeeService().getEmployee(empNo);
        this.empNo = employee.getEmpNo();
        this.empName = employee.getEmpName();
        this.ibu = employee.getIbu();
        this.designation = employee.getDesignation();
    }
}
```

```
  package employee;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    private int empNo;
    private String empName;
    private String ibu;
    private String designation;

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }
    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getIbu() {
        return ibu;
    }
    public void setIbu(String ibu) {
        this.ibu = ibu;
    }
    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
}
```

```
package employee;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class EmployeeService {

    public List<EmployeeEntity> getEmployeeList(){
        List<EmployeeEntity> empList = new ArrayList<EmployeeEntity>();
        EntityManager em = null;
        try{
            EntityManagerFactory emf =
                    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Employee-
                            Details");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
            et.begin();
            Query query = em.createQuery("select empNo from employee ");
            empList = query.getResultList();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //log the exception
        }
        return empList;
    }

    public EmployeeEntity getEmployee(int empNo){
        EmployeeEntity employee = new EmployeeEntity();
        EntityManager em = null;
        try{
            EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Employee-Details");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
            employee = em.find(EmployeeEntity.class, empNo);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //log the exception
        }
        finally{
            if( em != null){
                em.clear();
            }
        }
        return employee;
    }
}
```

```
<faces-config version="1.2"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
       <display-name>Employee</display-name>
       <from-view-id>/index.jsp</from-view-id>
    </navigation-rule>
    <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>employee</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>employee.EmployeeBean
            </managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Generating Employee Report</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>   
</web-app>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshots of the code is not a good idea, can't copy / paste with modifications or search.

Comment: I am going to edit it.

Comment: Does the "select" appear in the rendered page, only missing employees? If yes, have you tried to trace and see if employees are actually loading?

Comment: How do you pretend to select an employee without declaring a `value` attribute in the `selectOneMenu` itself? You're hacking it using a `valueChange` listener. This is, however, the less advisable choice to go with.

Comment: Alexandre Lavoie "select" appear on the rendered page. I posted picture above.

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: Xtreme Biker I am just learning how to integrate JPA and JSF from this page http://www.javabeat.net/integrating-jsf-and-jpa/. Unfortunately not everything is explained in details. So I am trying to put all of it together. I am not sure about this part you are asking me.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, I am using JSF 2.2. You can see image above.

Comment: Well. I would recommend to stop learning this way, you will only get frustrated and will hate two wonderful technologies. To begin, this article explains how to integrate JPA 1 and JSF 1.2. Note that JPA is currently in version 2.1 and JSF is in version 2.2. I can clearly note that you're not using JSF 2.2 benefits at all by seeing you're still using (deprecated) JSP as view instead of Facelets and that your persistence.xml file complies to 1_0. Also, JSF 2.2 requires Servlet 3.0 to work, but you have declared to use Servlet 2.5, check your web.xml file.

Comment: So, after crashing against reality (which happens a lot =\\) then you will realize that it would be better learning one of these technologies at a time. After learning each, you will have a better understanding of the scopes of these technologies and will have a better understanding on how to mix them. Personal note: JSF 1.2 is far far away from JSF 2.2 and JPA 2.1 gives enough power to rolllback to JPA 1.x resources.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza. Yes. I tried separately JSF and JPA but it is far away from this what I have to know. I figure out somehow I can mix them and wanted to try that. Could you please help me to put it all together? So in web.xml I changed <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">  is it correct?

Comment: Such an answer would be too broad for this site.

Comment: So do you mean it doesn't make sense to work on this example? Would I really have to change a lot? Stackoverflow has also chat. I could meet on chat.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the `value` to the `selectOneMenu`, the `valueChangeListener` attribute accepts a method-binding expression representing a value change listener method to be notified when a new value has been set for this input component. A value change listener method must be a public method that takes a `ValueChangeEvent` parameter, with a return type of void. It's not the same as the `value` property.

Your page.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selEmpNo"
    valueChangeListener="#{employee.employeeReport}"
    onchange="submit()" value="#{employee.myvalue}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" />
<f:selectItems value="#{employee.empNoList}" id="emp"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

EmployeeBean

```
    package employee;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
    import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

    public class EmployeeBean {

        private String myValue;
        private String empName;
        private String ibu;
        private String designation;

        public String getMyValue() {
            return myValue;
        }

        public void setMyValue(String myValue) {
            this.myValue = myValue;
        }
```

Regards

Source [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneMenu.html)